# GetString always return default language resource

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-core, localization, resx

I have a microservice in .Net-Core that have to handle some resources in a resx file and return them based on the culture I provide with a call to an API so I will not use the culture of the current thread, but when I call the method GetString(key, culture) it always return the default language.
I have 2 resx file at the moment: resource.resx and resource.it-IT.resx if i call the api with the it-IT culture string I always get the translation in the resource.resx file and not in the resource.it-IT.resx file

The resx files are in another project called Localization

I have a generic method where I pass the Enum I have to localize and the type of the file where the localization is stored, then I compose the key of the resource and call the GetString method.
I have also tried changing the culture of the current thread with

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureName);
```

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum e, Type resourceType, string cultureName)
{
   var rm = new ResourceManager(resourceType);

   var resourceDisplayName = rm.GetString(e.GetType().Name + "_" + e, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName));

   return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceDisplayName) ? string.Format("[[{0}]]", e) : resourceDisplayName;
 }
```

I have investigated a bit more and in the resource manager when I inspect it I have 3 resourceSet

```
resource
resource.it
resource.it-IT
```

If I inspect inside these 3 resource set I have all my resource always in English it seems that the resource manager doesn't load the resx italian file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this: [NetCore Bug](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24786) I managed to solve my problem, first of all I have refactored my method to this:

```
 public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum e, Type resourceType, string cultureName)
    {
        var rm = new ResourceManager(resourceType.FullName, resourceType.Assembly);

        var key = $"{e.GetType().Name}_{e}";
        var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
        var resourceDisplayName = rm.GetString(key, culture);

        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourceDisplayName) ? string.Format("[[{0}]]", e) : resourceDisplayName;
    }
```

Then I have removed the reference to the Localization project from the API project and only left that reference in another project that is then referenced from the API project

Answer (score 0):

About your `resource.resx` and `resource.it-IT.resx` files, please check if your key is the same in both the files. If the key you are trying to access is not available, the code automatically redirects to default file (resource.resx).

This link will help complete implementation of [Localization and Globalization](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/globalization-and-localization-in-Asp-Net-mvc-4/)

Comment: Yes, the keys are present in both file